# A really nightmarish SF novel by a famous author

Tags: story-identification, space

I read this SF novel at least 40 years ago. I read it in French, in a rather slim paperback, but I know it was a translation from English and it was by a very well-known SF author. Alas, I forgot who he was. I also do not remember the cover.

A dozen or so men and women are sent to some strange planet. They are all scientists. There are no other humans on that planet and they don't know what they are supposed to do. They see a mysterious building, but each of them interprets it differently. I think each of them tries to reach it to gain some power.

Anyway it turns into an "and then there were none" story.  They start to kill each other or to be killed by some of the many hazards of that planet.

When the last one is killed, the reader realises that it was a collective dream thanks to some apparatus that combines their brain waves: they all wake up.

This is when it becomes even **more** nightmarish: they are, in fact, in a disabled spaceship lost in deep space. No hope to be saved, they will die a slow death when the resources in food and energy of the ship are exhausted. They combine their minds in these collective dreams to avoid thinking continuously about their fate, worse than any of these nightmares.

Comment: It's the P K Dick novel, erm, that I've forgotten but it's been asked about many times here.

Comment: [A Maze of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Maze_of_Death).

Comment: I can post this as an answer if you want, but it's a dupe - [Novel about people living in a virtual reality on a spaceship, only discovering this over time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55152/novel-about-people-living-in-a-virtual-reality-on-a-spaceship-only-discovering).

Comment: @JohnRennie   That was fast ! You are right, it is A Maze of Death.  If you post an answer before it is counted as a dupe, you can get 15+10 points since I'll also upvote you !

Comment: I feel a bit squeamish about posting an answer when it's really obvious, as it seems like getting rep for no work. That's just me! :-) Anyhow since you've confirmed it I'll close this as  dupe.

Comment: @JohnRennie It was obvious to you, but not to me ! I would gladly have given you the 15+10 reps. Thanks for finding it for me !

Comment: The French translation would be titled "Au bout du labyrinthe"

Comment: Kind of funny that this one came up around the same time as a question about a "book about a death maze, but not *A Maze of Death*".